# ios UILabel setFrame error

Tags: ios, uilabel

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.forwardView setFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 40.0+height, 296.0, rootViewHeight-15.0)];

    self.forwardView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/250.0 green:153.0/250.0 blue:153.0/250.0 alpha:100].CGColor;
    self.forwardView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(12.0f, 40.0f, 288.0f , height);
    [self.tvContent setFrame:frame];
}


[self.tvContent setFrame:frame]; //crash?
```

Exception message:

```
-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7894c00
2013-05-21 10:44:54.677 Sohappy[22295:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7894c00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1eb5012 0x19aae7e 0x1f404bd 0x1ea4bbc 0x1ea494e 0xfb407 0xfc20b 0x9d01c7 0x9d0232 0x9d04da 0x9e78e5 0x9e79cb 0x9e7c76 0x9e7d71 0x9e889b 0x9e8e93 0x8ef13f7 0x9e8a88 0x93b9 0x99df83 0x99e4ed 0x13a85b3 0x1e74376 0x1e73e06 0x1e5ba82 0x1e5af44 0x1e5ae1b 0x24e27e3 0x24e2668 0x8eeffc 0x2acd 0x29f5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

UILabel in .xib , UseAutoLayout, ios sdk 6.1

Comment: Show the code where you've declared `forwardView`, `height`, and `rootViewHeight`...

Comment: float height = [self calcNewsContentHeight:text WithWidth:288.0f];
float rootViewHeight = [self calcNewsContentHeight:text1 WithWidth:288.0f];
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *forwardView;

Comment: crash at [self.tvContent setFrame:frame];

Comment: Show the property declaration for `tvContent` is it NOT a `UIView`? Where else in your code do you assign values to the `tvContent` property?

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tvContent;
tvContent is UILabel, in .h

Comment: thanks, stupit mistake，self.tvContent = [rowData objectForKey:@"News"];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to set the frame of an `NSString` - something that doesn't exist. `self.tvContent` is an NSString, not a UILabel as you seem to have suspected.

---

This is a good chance to learn how to read exceptions. I'll break it down for you here:

```
-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7894c00
2013-05-21 10:44:54.677 Sohappy[22295:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7894c00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1eb5012 0x19aae7e 0x1f404bd 0x1ea4bbc 0x1ea494e 0xfb407 0xfc20b 0x9d01c7 0x9d0232 0x9d04da 0x9e78e5 0x9e79cb 0x9e7c76 0x9e7d71 0x9e889b 0x9e8e93 0x8ef13f7 0x9e8a88 0x93b9 0x99df83 0x99e4ed 0x13a85b3 0x1e74376 0x1e73e06 0x1e5ba82 0x1e5af44 0x1e5ae1b 0x24e27e3 0x24e2668 0x8eeffc 0x2acd 0x29f5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here's what you are interested in:

```
-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7894c00
```

The system is giving you the class of the object and the message you tried to send it - in this case an NSString that you tried to call `setFrame:` on.

This information coupled with that you know which line is crashing makes for an easy conclusion: `self.tvContent` is an `NSString` where you were probably expecting a `UILabel`.

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tvContent;
tvContent is UILabel, in .h

Comment: @user At some point during the running of your app, you are setting this property equal to a `UILabel`.

Comment: thanks, stupit mistake，self.tvContent = [rowData objectForKey:@"News"];

Answer (score 1):

```
-[__NSCFString setFrame:]
```

Your app thinks that tvContent is a string, not a view. Make sure your outlet is connected to your UI correctly. Additionally, if you have a property for tvContent, it needs to be an owning reference (eg strong (under ARC) or retain (non-ARC)).

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tvContent;
tvContent is UILabel, in .h

Comment: Change it from weak to strong, if all is well, it should work.

Comment: thanks, stupit mistake，self.tvContent = [rowData objectForKey:@"News"];